# How to show SplashScreen on the second monitor?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

How to show SplashScreen on the second monitor? Now it shows only on primary monitor, but application starts on the secondary monitor.

Comment: I guess you mean how to show the splash screen on the same monitor that your application is going to start on, or how to detect which monitor your application is going to start on?

Comment: The WPF SplashScreen class heavily uses pinvoke to get the image displayed as fast as possible.  The native window location is hard-coded to be at the center of the main monitor.  Nothing you can tweak to alter that.  So the only decent workaround, other than giving up on SplashScreen, is to get your main window displayed on the main monitor as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no properties to control where the standard WPF splash screen shows up.

If you need to change the default behavior you need to do your own implementation.   [An example is available here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2007/12/10/splash-screen-to-improve-wpf-application-perceived-cold-startup-performance.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 'Screen' class with the WindowStartupLocation property of your splash screen (I assume you are using a Window for this).

Like:

```
Window someWindow = new SomeWindow();
someWindow.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual;
someWindow.Left = Screen.AllScreens[1].Bounds.Left;
someWindow.Top = Screen.AllScreens[1].Bounds.Top;
```

If needed you can center it yourself ofcourse. Take the screen height and the window height and calculate the center.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the System.Windows.Forms.Screen class. 
You can use `Screen.GetWorkingArea()` to get the current display, and then set the location of the splash screen based on that.  `Screen.FromControl()` and `Screen.AllScreens` may also be useful.